# how to create menu android with sherlock

Tags: android, styles, actionbarsherlock

I don't know how to create the bottom menu with sherlock on the button with the `ActionBarSherlock`, while my top menu is ok when created with sherlock.
I want the light style for my menu but I don't know how to create it with sherlock.

My code:

```java
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.submenu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/advancedsettings" >

        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/removerss"
                android:showAsAction="always"
                android:icon="@drawable/remove"
                android:title="Remove Rss" />

           <item
                android:id="@+id/addrss"
                android:showAsAction="always"
                android:title="Add Rss"
                android:icon="@drawable/add" />

        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

But this menu isn't connected with the style sherlock. So how can I create this menu with sherlock. Please if you can give some code to do it simple.

Comment: Your menu works but you want to style it? Or what do you mean?

Comment: my menu is working but as I can see my menu isnt connected with light style sherlock because that I want that my menu will be created with sherlock and that will solve my the style problem. I want to set background of my menu

Comment: Do you want to change the background of the overflow menu or the ActionBar?

Comment: to change color of menu background